# Access Forbidden for Apache2 VirtualHost Pointed at Windows User Directory

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server

I would like to configure a Apache2 VirtualHost to point at a directory on my user's directory path, e.g. \users\myuser\workspace

Whenever I try to access index.html on this site, I get a *403 Forbidden* message. My VirtualHost looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin dev@nul
    DocumentRoot "\Users\myuser\workspace"
    <Directory />
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        # This directive allows us to have apache2's default start page
        # in /apache2-default/, but still have / go to the right place
        #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>
    ServerName myserver.com
    ErrorLog "logs/myserver.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/myserver.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

I can however use a nested folder in the default *htdocs* folder:

```
DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\workspace"
```

But this isn't really ideal for what I'm trying to setup. I thought this was most likely a *Directory* directive problem, but I have configured that in the VirtualHost.

I have also tried relaxing the permissions on that folder (in Windows) and restarting the service, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

I'm using 64bit Apache2.4 from ApacheHaus configured as a service under Win 7.

My log output looks like this:

```
[Mon May 21 00:18:54.002485 2012] [authz_core:error] [pid 9412:tid 2680] [client 127.0.0.1:49864] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Users/myuser/workspace/index.html
```

I've tried changing the DocumentRoot to:

```
DocumentRoot C:/Users/myuser/workspace/index.html
```

...but this didn't fix the problem.